# Upload files within nested folders in AWS S3 using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking a way where I can upload files with in a nested folder using R Programming

I tried below functions which uploads either file or folder from aws.s3 package

```
library("aws.s3")
put_object("pathoftheobject", object = "filename", bucket = "bucketname")    
put_folder("foldername", bucket = "bucketname")
```

**Folder Structure and Files :**

```
ParentFolder
  SubFolder1
         File1
         File2
  SubFoler2
         File3
         File4
  ............
  SubFoldern
          Filen
```

Any guidance here will be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an R developer but in C# instead of creating folders under buckets, I use filename with / so S3 recognizes that as sub-folder.

my file name when uploading:

- ParentFolder/SubFolder1/Fil1
- ParentFolder/SubFolder1/Fil2
- ParentFolder/SubFolder2/Fil3

Answer (score 0):

aws.s3::s3sync function does the needful.

```
library(aws.s3)

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = access_key_id,
       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = secret_access_key,
       "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "eu-central-1",
       "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = session_token)

s3sync(files =dir(paste0(getwd(), "/Folder1Name/","Folder2Name"),recursive = T),
bucket = "BucketName", direction = "upload",verbose = TRUE)
```